# Debug.Assert / Retry, different behavior for 32 and 64 bit

Tags: c#, debugging

I'm using a WindowsFormsApplication right off the shelf. The only thing I added is the `Form1_Load` event-handler like below (Visual Studio Premium 2013):

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Debug.Assert(false);
}
```

1. For a 64 bit debug-build: When I hit a `Debug.Assert(false)` and push the **Retry** button the debugger breaks into the according line of source code.
2. For a 32 bit debug-build: When I hit exactly the same line as above the MessageBox shows up but hitting the **Retry** button does **not break**.

*Q1*: Why is the behavior different in the first place?

*Q2*: What can I do to make the 32 bit debug-build to break on hitting **Retry**?

**EDIT**

- *I do observe* the behavior as described above on Windows 8.1, Visual Studio Premium 2013 (Version 12.0.30723.00 Update 3).
- *I do **not** observe* the behavior as described above on Windows 8.1, Visual Studio Premium 2013 (Version 12.02.21005.1 REL). Specifically, when hitting **Retry** for the 32 bit debug-build the debugger breaks right into the code. The line containing the `Debug.Assert` is colored yellow in contrast to the 64 bit debug-build where the same line is colored green.

Comment: Funnily enough I [read this yesterday](http://blog.paulbetts.org/index.php/2010/07/20/the-case-of-the-disappearing-onload-exception-user-mode-callback-exceptions-in-x64/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today, I installed the Update 4 for Microsoft Visual Studio Premium 2013 (Version 12.0.31101.00 Update 4) and the problem is fixed. The Debugger halts on **Retry** for both 32 und 64 bit debug-builds.

(For whatever reason, the line containing the `Debug.Assert(false)`for 32 bit is yellow and for 64 bit is green.)